# Is there a function to get the new elements' order of RecyclerView after reorder it by drag and drop?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I building a photobook app, I need to reorder my picked images in my RecyclerView using drag and drop like this

[an example](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.photobook.android&hl=en_US)

actuly I drag and drop but I don't know how to get the new order!

I tried to access the list inside my adapter but it's order some times true and some times not

```
for (int i = 0; i < adapter.Hunts.size(); i++) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onMove: "+i+"  "+Hunts.get(i).getName());
}
```

I expect the output of printing that to be the same order of my list after drag and drop it's like it some times, but it getting be wrong after drag and drop some elements!

Answer (score 1):

This post solved my problem
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53106549/10244613)

the problem was inside my ItemTouchHelper

I used

```
public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                Collections.swap(Hunts, viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());

                adapter.notifyItemMoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
                return true;
            }
```

It shoud be

```
public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                int fromPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                int toPosition = target.getAdapterPosition();
                if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
                    for (int i = fromPosition; i < toPosition; i++) {
                        Collections.swap(Hunts, i, i + 1);
                    }
                } else {
                    for (int i = fromPosition; i > toPosition; i--) {
                        Collections.swap(Hunts, i, i - 1);
                    }
                }

                adapter.notifyItemMoved(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
                return true;
            }
```

that to reorder items inside my list.

Comment: I had the same problem, why is this necessary?